# Access pm2 status launched by user jenkins

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, jenkins, pm2

I have installed pm2 on my ubuntu machine.

```
which pm2
/usr/local/bin/pm2
```

This is the shell script to execute inside jenkins workspace.

```
export BUILD_ID=project
npm install
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --interpreter=/home/usrname/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.0/bin/node
```

With above script, pm2 start the process successfully.

```
┌─────┬───────────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  │ name          │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├─────┼───────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0   │ projectName│ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 8831     │ 0s     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 29.4mb   │ jenkins  │ disabled │
└─────┴───────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

But, whenever I do `pm2 status` on the machine nothings shows up.

I need to check the log of the process.

I think, it is running the `pm2` as user `jenkins`. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me for now

```
 sudo -H -u jenkins bash -c 'pm2 status && pm2 log 0' #pm2AsJenkins
```

I have added a comment so it is easier to get to the command with `CRTL +R`